# PagedListPager html helper not working in Mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

```
    [Authorize(Roles="Admin")]
public class AdminController : Controller
{
    Propertydb _db = new Propertydb();


    public ActionResult Index(int page = 1)
    {

        var Sale = (from m in _db.Properties
                    join p in _db.PropertyType on m.Typeofproperty equals p.PropTypeId
                    join r in _db.BedRoom on m.Roomdetails equals r.BedRoomId
                    join c in _db.Cities on m.CityId equals c.CityId
                    join l in _db.Areas on m.Locality_Id equals l.Locality_Id
                    where m.SaleorRent == "Sale" && m.Rejected == false
                    select new { m.Name, m.Id,m.Photo,m.Age, m.SaleorRent,m.Status, l.Locality,p.PropertyTypes,m.BuiltUpArea,m.CreatedDate, c.City, m.Propertyvalue, r.BedRoom })
                     .Select(m => new SrchDetail
                      {
                          Id=m.Id,
                          Name = m.Name,
                          SaleorRent = m.SaleorRent,
                          Photo = m.Photo,
                          Age = m.Age,
                          City = m.City,
                          Locality = m.Locality,
                          Typeofproperty = m.PropertyTypes,
                          BuiltUpArea = m.BuiltUpArea,
                          Roomdetails = m.BedRoom,
                          CreatedDate = m.CreatedDate,
                          Propertyvalue = m.Propertyvalue,
                          Status = m.Status
                      }).ToList();
        ViewBag.sale = Sale;
        var Rent = (from m in _db.Properties
                    join p in _db.PropertyType on m.Typeofproperty equals p.PropTypeId
                    join r in _db.BedRoom on m.Roomdetails equals r.BedRoomId
                    join c in _db.Cities on m.CityId equals c.CityId
                    join l in _db.Areas on m.Locality_Id equals l.Locality_Id
                    where m.SaleorRent == "Rent" && m.Rejected == false
                    select new { m.Name, m.Id, m.Photo, m.Age, m.Status, m.SaleorRent, l.Locality, p.PropertyTypes, m.BuiltUpArea, m.CreatedDate, c.City, m.Monthlyrent, r.BedRoom })
                     .Select(m => new SrchDetail
                     {
                         Id = m.Id,
                         Name = m.Name,
                         SaleorRent = m.SaleorRent,
                         Photo = m.Photo,
                         Age = m.Age,
                         City = m.City,
                         Locality = m.Locality,
                         Typeofproperty = m.PropertyTypes,
                         BuiltUpArea = m.BuiltUpArea,
                         Roomdetails = m.BedRoom,
                         CreatedDate = m.CreatedDate,
                         Monthlyrent = m.Monthlyrent,
                         Status = m.Status
                     }).ToList();
        ViewBag.rent = Rent;
        //IPagedList<property> property_sale = _db.Properties.Where(rents => rents.SaleorRent == "Sale" && rents.Rejected == false).ToList().ToPagedList(page,10);

        //IPagedList<property> property_rent = _db.Properties.Where(rents => rents.SaleorRent == "Rent" && rents.Rejected == false).ToList();
        ViewData["Sale"] = Sale.ToPagedList(page, 10);
        ViewData["Rent"] = Rent.ToPagedList(page, 10);


        return View();
    }



The cshtml page for the controller is as follows : I have taken PagedLlist in        starting of the page. Is it necessary to use IpagedList here . I don't know what is the reason its showing error .
```

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

```
@model PagedList<Property.Models.SrchDetail>
@{

Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Adminproperty.cshtml";
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/PagedList.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />




<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#tabs").tabs();
    });
</script>
}


<div class="accordian-content-container1">
<h2>New Properties</h2>
<div id="tabs">
    <div class="tab-container">
        <div id="TabbedPanels1" class="TabbedPanels">
            <ul class="TabbedPanelsTabGroup">
                <li class="TabbedPanelsTab"><a href="#tabs-1">Sale</a></li>
                <li class="TabbedPanelsTab"><a href="#tabs-2">Rent</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="TabbedPanelsContentGroup">
                <div class="TabbedPanelsContent" id="tabs-1">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Photo</th>

                            <th>City</th>
                            <th>Locality</th>
                            <th>Type of Property</th>
                            <th>Room Details</th>
                            <th>Property Value</th>
                            <th>Built Up Area   </th>
                            <th>Posted On</th>
                            <th>Status</th>
                            <th>Action</th>
                        </tr>

                        @foreach (var item in ViewData["Sale"] as IPagedList<Property.Models.SrchDetail>)
                        {
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <img src="~/Images/Ads/@item.Photo" alt="" style="height:40px; width:40px;">
                                </td>

                                <td>
                                    @item.City
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @item.Locality
                                </td>

                                <td>
                                    @item.Typeofproperty
                                </td>

                                <td>
                                    @item.Roomdetails
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @item.Propertyvalue
                                </td>

                                <td>
                                    @item.BuiltUpArea
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @item.CreatedDate.ToShortDateString()
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @Html.ActionLink(Html.Encode(item.Status), "Status", new { id = item.Id })
                                </td>

                                <td>

                                    @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.Id }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Reject", "Reject", new { id = item.Id })
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        }

                    </table>
                </div>



 @Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page,  sale = ViewBag.sale }), new PagedListRenderOptions() { Display = PagedListDisplayMode.IfNeeded, DisplayPageCountAndCurrentLocation = true })

                <div class="TabbedPanelsContent" id="tabs-2">

                    <table width="100%" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" border="1" bordercolor="#dfdddd">
                        <tr>
                            <th>Photo</th>

                            <th>City</th>
                            <th>Locality</th>
                            <th>Type of Property</th>
                            <th>Room Details</th>
                            <th>Monthly Rent</th>
                            <th>Posted On</th>
                        </tr>
                        @foreach (var item in ViewData["Rent"] as IPagedList<Property.Models.SrchDetail>)
                        {
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <img src="~/Images/Ads/@item.Photo" alt="" style="height:40px; width:40px;">
                                </td>


                                <td>
                                    @item.City
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @item.Locality
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @item.Typeofproperty
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @item.Roomdetails
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @item.Monthlyrent
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @item.CreatedDate.ToShortDateString()
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @Html.ActionLink(Html.Encode(item.Status), "Status", new { id = item.Id })
                                </td>

                                <td>

                                    @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.Id }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Reject", "Reject", new { id = item.Id })
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        }

                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page, rent = ViewBag.rent }), new PagedListRenderOptions() { Display = PagedListDisplayMode.IfNeeded, DisplayPageCountAndCurrentLocation = true })
```

Whenever I comment the PagedList helper than everything works fine but the paging is not shown. Otherwise it shows the error that "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: You're not passing any model to your view in your controller...

Comment: No, Data is being passed through ViewData and received in cshtml as PagedList type.

Comment: But your Model in the view is null, since you're not passing the model to the view in the controller. In the controller you're putting data in ViewData, not the model. Either pass a model to your view so your Model is not null, or in your PagedListPager use ViewData instead of Model.

Comment: Can you show me by editing the pagedList helper ?

Comment: Either use `return View(Sale.ToPagedList(page, 10););` or `@Html.PagedListPager(ViewData["Sale"],` or Rent

Comment: It giving error if I write it the second way. Using first way I cannot write because I have to pass both the data for sale as well as rent

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62808/discussion-between-smoking-monkey-and-artm).

Answer (score 0):

```
ViewBag.sale = Sale.ToPagedList(page, 10);
ViewBag.rent = Rent.ToPagedList(page, 10);
```

In cshtml

```
     @Html.PagedListPager((IPagedList)ViewBag.rent, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page }), new PagedListRenderOptions() { Display = PagedListDisplayMode.IfNeeded, DisplayPageCountAndCurrentLocation = true })

     @Html.PagedListPager((IPagedList)ViewBag.sale, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page }), new PagedListRenderOptions() { Display = PagedListDisplayMode.IfNeeded, DisplayPageCountAndCurrentLocation = true })
```